# GeoServer force declared SRS

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver

How accurate is the 'force declared SRS' in GeoServer?

Does it fully transform the data into another coordinate system or is it more of an on-the-fly reprojection?

Comment: Force declared doesn't reproject it overrides the metadata

Answer (score 1):

"force declared SRS" is a simple metadata replacement, it does not change the coordinates of geometries at all. It's used to fix wrong or incomplete source CRS information (e.g., the source CRS can be correct, but it might not contain all the extra information available in the EPSG database, such as area of validity, optimal transformation paths to other CRSs).

If you want actual reprojection, use "reproject from native".

[See the official documentation for more details](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/webadmin/layers.html#coordinate-reference-systems).